# Which place in Middle East are these photos taken from?

Tags: where-on-earth, middle-east

I haven't seen this place yet.. can anyone tell me where this is? Seems beautiful and worth visiting

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good luck visiting Riyadh, unless you are a Saudi, from a Gulf state or get a job there you are unlikely to get a visa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These photos were taken in Riyadh, Saudi Arabia.

The last photo shows the [Alfaysaliya building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Faisaliyah_Center).